# infinite animation angular 4 animationBluider

Tags: angular, animation, infinite

I'm trying to create a vertical animation like an infinite autoplay carrousel without stop between transitions. 
I want to be able to make it stops and restarts in a very fluid way.

I'm using Anuglar 5 and Material + FlexLayout.

I'm also using AnimationBuilder, which is able to make a pause during an animation. It is working for a while then it blocks after the first loop is complete.

DEMO : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animationbuilder-infinite-bug

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="flow" >
      <div class="flow-block flow-block-p1 red" #flowBlocks></div>
      <div class="flow-block flow-block-p2 blue" #flowBlocks></div>
      <div class="flow-block flow-block-p3 green" #flowBlocks></div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.flow { position: relative; }
.flow-block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.flow-block-p1 {
  top: -100px;
}
.flow-block-p2 {
  top: -100px;
}
.flow-block-p3 {
  top: -100px;
}
```

In my component :

```
@ViewChildren('flowBlocks') flowBlocks: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  private animation_enter = [
    style({top: '100px'}),
    animate('10000ms', style({top: '0px'}))
  ];
  private animation_leave = [
    style({top: '0px'}),
    animate('10000ms', style({top: '-100px'}))
  ];

    ngAfterViewInit() {
this.flowBlocks.forEach((block, index) => {
      console.log(block, ' - ', index);
      this.flowBlocksPlayers['leave'].push(this.animationBuilder.build(this.animation_leave).create(block.nativeElement, {}));
      this.flowBlocksPlayers['enter'].push(this.animationBuilder.build(this.animation_enter).create(block.nativeElement, {}));
    });
  this.flowPlay(1);

}


  getNextBlockID(currentBlockID) {
    return (currentBlockID === 2 ? 0 : currentBlockID + 1);
  }

  getPreviousBlockID(currentBlockID) {
    return (currentBlockID === 0 ? 2 : currentBlockID - 1);
  }

flowPlay(id) {
    const enteringBlockID = id;
    const leavingBlockID = this.getNextBlockID(id);

    this.onFlowBlockEnter(enteringBlockID);
    this.onFlowBlockLeave(leavingBlockID);
  }

  onFlowBlockEnter(enteringBlockID) {
    this.flowBlocksPlayers['enter'][enteringBlockID].reset();

    this.flowBlocksPlayers['enter'][enteringBlockID].onDone(() => {
    });

    this.flowBlocksPlayers['enter'][enteringBlockID].play();
  }

  onFlowBlockLeave(leavingBlockID) {
    this.flowBlocksPlayers['leave'][leavingBlockID].reset();

    this.flowBlocksPlayers['leave'][leavingBlockID].onDone(() => {
      this.flowPlay(this.getNextBlockID(leavingBlockID));
    });

    this.flowBlocksPlayers['leave'][leavingBlockID].play();
  }
```

I need to split it into two animations so it is able to update the content of each div outside of the user's view and make it fluid.

I really don't understand why my animation is not working.

Thanks in advance !